# BLE scanning in background on ios

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

i have 2 devices .. both advertising and scanning a UUID . In both foreground and in background. Below is both the advertise and scan code both .

the problem is simple. 2 devices advertise and scan and try and discover each other in background.

In foreground both devices are able to discover each other fine.

However when we have both devices in background, they do not discover/ re-discover each other. Apple documentation already suggests that the CBperipheralallowduplicates key is ignored in background and therefore it will not rediscover already discovered devices.

however, going through some other posts on stackoverflow , i found the scan is reset if you restart scan in background.

to achieve this , i send an external push notification ( which is duly received ) and it restarts the scan in background.

However, it produces rediscovery in only 'some cases' . I have tested this with numerous devices: 6s, 7 , 7 plus , 8 , iphoneX , ipad etc and multiple other phones.

**It worked on some and it does not work on others.**  Ios versions are 12.3.1 on all

there is no pattern emerging here either - it works on some 7 and on some 7 it doesnt, it works on some iphone 6s and on some it doesnt.

**Can someone help understand what is the issue here ? what is causing this behaviour ? and how can we make the rediscovery consistent ?**

other things that we have already tried : 
1. putting a delay in stop and start scan 
2. logging to see if the state of the central manager changes - none detected.

```
let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: "8D38A460-2F8A-4D1C-8509-324B0377AE44") let service = CBMutableService(type: serviceUUID, primary: true)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager! }

extension AppDelegate: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) 
{
        switch peripheral.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            os_log("advertising")
            peripheralManager.add(service)
            peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [serviceUUID]])
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

below is scan code:

func scan() {
        centralManager.stopScan()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0)
        {let scanOptions = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true] as [String : Any]

            self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID], options: scanOptions)

        }

    }
}


    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        os_log("discover: %{public}s", peripheral.description)
    }
}
```

i expect it to show re-discovery consistently on all devices

Comment: Did you find any solution that has similar problem in me?Thanks